# Is there a way of solving this equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I came across the following equation and was not sure that it could be solved by algebraic means. How can this equation be solved?
$$\ln(x)=x-3$$
Thank you

Comment: The only explicit solution is given in terms of Lambert function

Comment: ^^ $\to \ln{x} = x - 3 \to x = e^{x} \cdot e^{-3} \to -xe^{-x} = -e^{-3}$. Now use lambert W to approximate.

Comment: Are you familiar with the lambert W function?

Answer (score 1):

Raising both sides to the power of $e$ gives
$$x=e^{x-3}$$
Now recall the Lambert W function, or product log function, which has the property that
$$W\left(xe^x\right)=x$$
For positive $x$ (Which is satisfied since your ln gets rid of negatives anyways), which contains both the 0th and -1st branch of the function.

Hence, we divide both sides by $e^x$ and negate both sides to get
$$xe^{-x}=e^{-3}$$
$$\implies -xe^{-x}=-e^{-3}$$
Taking the Lambert W (with both branches) of both sides and multiplying out the negative gives our answers to be
$$x=-W_{-1}\left(-e^{-3}\right), -W_0\left(-e^{-3}\right)$$